# Change fading between images with seekbar android

Tags: android

Can anybody help. So i have an imageview and customseekbar. According to the count of pictures, seekbar has nodes. The picture would be changed by reaching next node in seekbar. This all implemented and work fine. And now i need following: As log as i move a thumb to the next node, the first picture should slowly vanished and the second picture should overlay the first ( so called fading), to compare two pictures visually. It is needed for example to compare picture with the font which was 100 years ago and actual font. Have anybody an idea. Animation with duration is not a solution for me. It should be done manually with thumb on seekbar. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solution is SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener. You can use "alpha" (float) property of both ImageView's. When user moves to next node, alpha value of first image will decrease from 1 to 0 and value of second should increase and vice versa. If you targetingApi >= Honeycomb you could use advantage of ObjectAnimator, this will give somewhat smoother animation if you use right interpolator and will react properly in onStartTrackingTouch and onStopTrackingTouch callbacks. Using his methods you can react on start/stop of touch, and listen for progress change. You can also setMax of SeekBar to value greater than 100, to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try on weekend.